# Should I use shared_ptr or return unique_ptr.get()?

Tags: c++, mysql

I have a class with a pointer to a MySQL connection. It only makes sense for this pointer and connection to be constant. However, other classes need the connection so one way of dealing with this is to have the class be

```
class A {
     std::unique_ptr < sql::Connection > conn;

   public:
     const sql::Connection* getConnection ();
}
```

Or variants of this (like returning a reference or adding `const` at different places in the declaration of `conn`.  The implementation of `getConnection` is like

```
const sql::Connection* A::getConnection() {
  return conn.get();
}
```

I am wandering however if I should be using instead `std::shared_ptr` and returning a copy of the pointer. In which scenario would one choose either approach?

Comment: So what is `A`? How do the other classes have access to `A`?

Comment: `A` takes care of checking that the needed MySQL database exists and is usable. Other classes don't have direct access to `A` but rather need the connection managed by `A`, by receiving a reference to `conn` as parameters in their methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your application is designed in a way that can be proven that an SQL connection cannot be used after an instance of your `A` object goes out of scope and gets destroyed, then using a `unique_ptr`, and obtaining the underlying pointer using `get()`, is sufficient.

If, on the other hand, it's possible that there might be a need to use the connection after this `A` object is destroyed, then the `unique_ptr` would obviously not be sufficient, and a `shared_ptr` is in order, here.

There are some other possibilities to consider. For example, having an instance of the `A` class itself being dynamically allocated, and using a `std::shared_ptr<A>` to refer to it, in places where it's needed; this proving, by contract, that a given `A` remains in existence as long as the underlying SQL connection is needed. In such cases, the `unique_ptr` won't itself have much of a value-added. However, it might make sense to take this approach if `A` implements some value-added functionality on top of the underlying SQL connection.

Comment: Also, if an object of class `A` truly owns the resource AND the pointer can never be null, he should return a reference instead of a raw pointer.

Answer (score 1):

If your application is multi_threaded, opening multiple instances of the database connection is preferable and hence using std::unique_ptr in each instance. This will avoid bottlenecks during sharing of database resources.